# Restarting a task after its state is changed by another task

Tags: c++, task, state-machine

I have a C++ design where I have two state machines, `A` and `B`, running in two different FreeRTOS tasks, like this:

```
A::task()
{
    while (1)
    {
        switch (m_state)
        {
        case A1:
            // Do A1 stuff
            break;
        case A2:
            // [1] Do A2 stuff before yielding to B::task()
            // [2] Do more A2 stuff after resuming from B::task()
            break; // [3]
        default:
            break;
        } // switch: state
    } // while: task loop
}

B::task()
{
    while (1)
    {
        switch (m_state)
        {
        case B1:
            // Do B1 stuff
            break;
        case B2:
            // Do B2 stuff
            break;
        default:
            break;
        } // switch: state
    } // while: task loop
}
```

Now, `B` has the ability to change the state of `A` (asynchronously, via callback). This all works fine, but what I would like to do is have `A`'s machine "restart" when its state is changed (i.e, `break` from what it was doing last time the task was running **[1]**), so that the code in the old state **[2]** doesn't continue before hitting the `break` **[3]** and the state change taking effect.

Can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: It sounds like you want a condition variable. That is, when B sets A's state to A2, A will then wait on a condition variable that b will notify on. A  simpler example would be that you have a mutex that B takes before setting A's state to A2. After A completes its A2 stuff, it attempts to grab the mutex, which will yield until B has released it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I believe what you want to do is not a reasonable possibility the way you've described.  When task A gets preempted, the scheduler saves the context of task A and restores the context of task B.  The saved context of task A includes the local variables that were in use when it got switched out and the program counter (address of the instruction that was executing).  In order to restore context A so that it runs at a different place you'd have to edit task A's saved context before restoring it.  And I don't think that's a reasonable thing to do.

I'm not sure this is a good idea but consider whether task B can delete and recreate task A whenever task B changes the state of task A.  Perhaps then task A could restart whenever task B changes A's state.

Another idea is to make it so that task A cannot be preempted while it is in the middle of a task.  If tasks A's states are too big to disable preemption for so long then perhaps the states can be divided into multiple smaller states.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did feel like I wouldn't be able to achieve it nicely. Recreating the tasks isn't really an option in the context of the system behaviour, so that's that idea quashed. I stall the scheduler very infrequently for time-critical functionality, but it's not really an option to do it in a larger context.

Comment: Is there a way of querying a variable upon re-entry into a task, that sits lower than the task itself? I suppose kind of like a semaphore from the scheduler's point of view?

Comment: A task is not aware that it was preempted.  So you can't make the task do something different when it is resumed.  The task's code is the task's code.  I don't think it's reasonable to insert extra code instructions at the point where it resumes.  The test for preemption would have be in the code at compile time and then you'd have to repeat the test after every statement because you don't know ahead of time where the preemption will occur.

Comment: @EdKing, Are you familiar with [QP from www.state-machine.com](http://www.state-machine.com/)?  It's a state-machine framework (technically an "active object" framework) that may suit your design style better than an RTOS.  I'm not being a salesman but honestly think you might be interested and that it might be helpful for your application.  There would be big learning curve though.